# Chart won't evaluate Tooltip as String

Tags: c#, charts, tooltip

I want use my tooltip text as string.

When i try this `MessageBox.Show(chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendToolTip); ===> Output: #MIN-#MAX`

`MessageBox.Show(chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendToolTip.toString()); ===> Output: #MIN-#MAX`

i want output string is "1-49".

[MyChart Image](http://i.hizliresim.com/XYz9aj.png)

Comment: Can't you just output something like String.Format({0}-{1},chart1.Series["Series1"].MinValue, chart1.Series["Series1"].MaxValue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can let the chart evaluate the ToolTip without the respective mouse actions.

But similar to Marton's suggestion you can evaluate the ToolTip formula yourself, maybe like this:

```
Series S1 = chart1.Series["Series1"];
string legendToolTip = S1.Points.FindMinByValue("Y1").YValues[0] +
              " - " +  S1.Points.FindMaxByValue("Y1").YValues[0] ;
MessageBox.Show(legendToolTip );
```